# Render XML content in a div element

Tags: html, css, xml

I have an XML file representing a menu of a restaurant and I want to render it's content in a div element from an HTML file. I must use only HTML5 and CSS3. How can I do this?

Comment: This question is very unclear. Where does the XML come from? Are you using any server-side technology or is it loaded via AJAX and you have to do this in-browser? What do you mean by "in a div element from a HTML file"? Do you want to actually change an existing HTML file on disk, or are you generating the whole file, or are you changing a document loaded in the browser already?

Comment: @millimoose: the XML and HTML files are on disk, created by me. I don't use any server side technology. All I want is to display the content of the XML file inside the HTML file, but keeping the layout and styling that I've done, without using XSLT

Comment: @Yoshi: yes, it is a project. And one assignment is to create a page of the website based on a XML file. And my clients asked me to create a website for a restaurant+nightclub, and the page based on XML data file to be the menu of the restaurant.

Comment: have a look at [xhr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest). If you can load your document, you'll have everything javascript has to offer to read from the xml and write to your html.

Comment: I shouldn't use javascript.

Comment: @SorinAdrianCarbunaru Your task is impossible without **a** programming language, and picking whether you use it to modify the file on the disk, or modify the document in the browser.

Comment: What if you were to include the XML file inside your static HTML page as a frame, and then style that XML page with XSLT, which is just styling for XML documents?

Comment: we didn't study XSLT...the task is to create a page based on an XML file... and it was my idea to try to display the XML in the div, because it would look better, keeping the layout, styling etc...I know that I can add CSS to the XML file and render it, but I didn't want simply to display the XML file....

Comment: @huzzah You can *style* XML just fine with CSS. XSLT is hardly "just styling for XML languages", it's a full blown and not exactly intuitive programming language that allows for arbitrary transformations of XML documents to text. It's closer to a pattern-matching pure-functional language than to CSS. (XSLT 2.0 also has pretty much zero support in browsers.)

Comment: @millimoose I stand corrected.  My misguided point was similar to the first example you gave in your answer below.

Comment: @huzzah It's a perfectly valid approach really, my point was more that that allowing XSLT and banning Javascript is a very, very arbitrary restriction. (And both are overkill if you just need to set up fonts, colors, and maybe `display` modes.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Try this:

```
<embed src="file.xml" />
```

Comment: Hilariously enough, this actually works, and the XML nodes might be styleable.

Comment: @SorinAdrianCarbunaru It works in the Big Three if you use the "more standard" `<object>` tag instead of `<embed>`.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on Praveen's answer (mostly for the sake of providing a more complete code example), it is in fact possible to display XML content and style it with CSS using the following incantations:

#### `foo.html`

```
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <object data="foo.xml" />
</body>

</html>
```

#### `foo.xml`

```xml
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="foo.css"?>
<foo>
    abc
    <bar>def</bar>
    ghi
</foo>
```

#### `foo.css`

```css
bar {
    color: red;
}
```

You might have to live with this not working across all browsers, because there's no standard way I'm aware of transcluding a XML document from a HTML one without using a programming language. (Although the above works in FF, Chrome, and IE.)

That is, unless copy-pasting the XML into the body of the HTML document counts. (Which is technically not including XML, strictly speaking, but a bunch of "invalid" HTML tags that just happen to look a lot like XML. This is possible because HTML explicitly allows unknown tags for the sake of forward compatibility, and as of HTML5 allows some XMLisms like self-closed tags for compatibility with XHTML.) I.e. the following is perfectly legal, and should accomplish the same as the above example, although it still makes me vaguely uncomfortable:

#### `foo2.html`

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    bar {
        color: red;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Contents of foo.xml go here -->
    <foo>
        abc
        <bar>def</bar>
        ghi
    </foo>
</body>

</html>
```

That said, both of these are IMO less dumb than using XSLT, in that it's actually possible to figure out what's going on.